# Question about the food, service, atmosphere ratings of Places API

Tags: google-api, google-reviews

I have a question. I checked the documentations of the Places Api. According to the documentation. i can fetch the newest reviews ratings, but I couldn't find any information about how to fetch subratings of reviews such as atmosphere, food, and service ratings. Does anyone know whether it is possible or not?

I made some research but couldn't find anything about it.